# Image replacement issue

Tags: css, html, image-replacement

I am confused by selecting the best technique for image replacement in web design.

Here at this weblog some techniques are provided:

http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/

Which technique in image replacement is better?

Why should we use css image replacement when we can use 'alt' attribute of img tag to put some text ?

Answer (score 1):

The `alt` attribute can't handle CSS. Image replacement displays a styled element instead of the image, which is good for image-less (if they exist) people.

As for the "best", I'd say **No. 3** is good. No extra markup and no issues. All the other solutions suffer from one or the other.

Comment: i see many use these technique for putting their logo.i think the logo could simply put by img and this alt attribute and no styled element is needed.

Comment: Then do what you think. Some like their site to look nice when there are no images.